# Proving key equivalence across different elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

We can use the technique described in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60129) to prove key equivalence across two elliptic curves of different order. I'm wondering if modifying the technique as described below would compromise anything.

So, let's say I have committed to 2 points $A$ and $A'$ on two different elliptic curves with generators $G$ and $G'$. The curves are of orders $q$ and $q'$ such that $q < q'$. I've also publicly committed to a large random number $h$. I would like to prove that $A = a \cdot G$ and $A' = a \cdot G'$ while using this number $h$. I am thinking I could do the following:

1. Compute $r = a \cdot h$ (this the main difference from the linked answer).
2. Compute $T = r \cdot G$ and $T' = r \cdot G'$.
3. Compute $u = H(G, G', A, A', T, T')$ and use it to compute $v = r + a \cdot u$.
4. The proof is then $(T, T', v)$.

The verification works same as before: compute $u$ and verify that $v \cdot G = T + u \cdot A$ and $v \cdot G' = T' + u \cdot A'$. The verifier can also verify that I've used the number $h$ because $h \cdot A = T$.

Does the fact that I changed the first step as described above break anything?

---

**Edit**: the above approach makes it trivial to recover $a$ - so, it doesn't work. Maybe there is another approach that would work?